# Does DWR uses polling OR push based concept?

Tags: java, ajax, dwr, reverse-ajax

While DWR is said to be reverse AJAX technology, I wanted to understand if it is actually uses push based concept OR is in reality a polling based..

It would be great if you could elaborate the same with simple example to understand the concept better.

Answer (score 0):

DWR can use both depending on the browser used.

If the browser supports push DWR can use this.

If the browser does not support push then DWR will use a polling mechanism.

You can read all this in the [documentation](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/index.html).

Comment: Oh...I never really knew it can be browser-based...did not find any specific browsers mentioned in the documentation though...